# Not able to start Inspector session in Appium

Tags: appium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxpZP.png)I am trying to start Appium Inspector session But I am getting the attached error. I have added JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_SDK but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

open CMD as admin and type "adb shell"
You'll see the name of your emulator.. (not "Android Emulator")

Answer (score 0):

Your path seems wrong, it should be just `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.13\bin`, you have `\bin\bin` at the end instead.